# How to style xmlns imported SVG image?

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, xml-namespaces

I am importing an SVG image in my Angular 8 project. I generate this image with this HTML

```
<div #workflow class="left_pane"></div>
```

and this TS:

```
@ViewChild("workflow", {static: true})
  public mermaidDiv;
```

When inspecting the screen in the developer tools, the generated SVG code looks something like this:

```
<svg id="graphDiv" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="max-width: 290.859375px;" viewBox="0 0 290.859375 421.78125">…</svg>
```

This correctly generates the image as needed. However, I am unable to alter the max-width property that is set with this SVG. I have tried the following in my component.scss code:

```
svg#graphDiv {
  min-width: 1000px !important;
}
```

But this does nothing. How can I override the max-width setting for this xmlns SVG with the user stylesheet? Is there a way to override the element.style ?

Comment: Only by removing it from the style definition, because style trumps everything

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman this <style> code isn't actually written in my project. That's what is displayed in developer tools when I inspect the page

Comment: really I don't know how you generate the svg, you can try use "transform:scale" in a outer div -if only write the svg looks like work max-width:200px!important, a fool example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gzqmef?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css, but I imagine that the way to generate the .svg add this "max-width"

Comment: Then you have to use javascript to remove the style attribute

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing that in an Angular project. How can I do that? @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be working because you are in component file. Try putting the code into styles.scss file.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the value of `max-width` by setting it to `none !important`:

```css
svg#graphDiv {
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

```html
<svg id="graphDiv" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="max-width: 290.859375px;" viewBox="0 0 290.859375 421.78125">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not do anything to override the existing max-width set by the imported SVG.